# PostgreSQL 9.4 pg_restore is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

recently i'm trying to restore a table in local DB or production DB and whatever i do, seems like pg_restore can't connect to the local or remote DB.

It is just exiting with `code 0` or just exiting without any errors or result code.

No data inserted or table schema updated

example command :

```
pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "homemarket" --no-password  --data-only --table test_table --schema public --verbose "D:\folder\backup\21.06.2016.backup"
```

tried with options `--password`, tried to specify the connection String, tried different DB's, different tables and schemes, different option. Nothing help. Completely can't understand why it's not working :(

Example string just executing and exiting without errors or any result code.

**ADD** the log of backup file creation:

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --verbose --file "D:\folder\backup\21.06.2016.backup" --table "public.condos" "homemarket"
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading event triggers
pg_dump: finding extension members
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "condos"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "condos"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "condos"
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading foreign key constraints for table "condos"
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading triggers for table "condos"
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: dumping contents of table condos

Process returned exit code 0.
```

Comment: what is the size of `D:\folder\backup\21.06.2016.backup`?..

Comment: .....   45  kilobyte .....

Comment: I believe it is empty - only some structure and comments. how did you make a backup?..

Comment: backup log uploaded here. BTW even structure is not updating. If i create empty table for this purpose, after i trying pg_restore, it is strill have empty structure.